# Не создаются/не обновляются столбцы в postgreSql при изменении их в коде

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, nhibernate

Кто знает, почему не создается таблица и не обновляются столбцы в postgreSql  при изменении их в коде?

Я создаю новые сущности запускаю проект, но они в базе не создались.

appsettings:

```
"PostgreCabinetDb": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=password123;",
    "IsSchemaUpdate": true
};
```

и вот мои настройки провайдера:

```
if (_schemaUpdate)
{
    cfg.ExposeConfiguration(x => new SchemaUpdate(x).Execute(false, true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с созданием таблицы:

```
if (_schemaUpdate)
{
    cfg.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
    {
        new SchemaUpdate(x).Execute(false, true);
        new SchemaExport(x).Create(false, true);
    });
}
```

Comment: но это не правильно, оно удаляет предыдущие записи